# An optimized method to compare IP addresses with wildcards in PHP?

Tags: php, string, performance

Anyone know of an effective and secure method to see if this input:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

matches against something similar to this array of inconsistent filters (note that 200.100.*.* could be expressed as just 200.100.*) with wildcards indicated by *'s:

```
array(
  '192.168.1.*',
  '192.168.2.1*',
  '10.0.0.*',
  '200.100.*.*',
  '300.200.*',
)
```

**Update**

Thoughts?

```
foreach($instanceSettings['accessControl']['allowedIpV4Addresses'] as $ipV4Address) {
    echo 'Now checking against '.$ipV4Address.'.';

    // Compare each octet
    $ipV4AddressOctets = String::explode('.', $ipV4Address);
    $remoteIpV4AddressOctets = String::explode('.', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $remoteIpV4AddressIsAllowed = true;
    for($i = 0; $i < Arr::size($ipV4AddressOctets); $i++) {
        echo 'Comparing '.$ipV4AddressOctets[$i].' against '.$remoteIpV4AddressOctets[$i].'.';
        if($ipV4AddressOctets[$i] != $remoteIpV4AddressOctets[$i] && $ipV4AddressOctets[$i] != '*') {
            echo 'No match.';
            $remoteIpV4AddressIsAllowed = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Get out of the foreach if we've found a match
    if($remoteIpV4AddressIsAllowed) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible for you to also specify netmask of each ip address? i.e.: `'192.168.100.251/26'` or `'192.168.100.251' => '26'` (that 26 bit mask may not even be valid for the given IP address, it's just for an example's sake)
If you can specify netmasks, then calculating IP address validity is as easy as `if ($first_addr_of_mask > $ip && $last_addr_of_mask < $ip)`

Comment: I would not do this in PHP but rather on the server firewall.

Answer (score 12):

I haven't bench-marked this, but I would opt to use the method that networking hardware/software uses...

Replace any * with 0 and 255.
Convert the IPs to integers

So if 255.255.255.* becomes 255.255.255.0 and 255.255.255.255
Then do ip2long function on these two ips.

Then you can convert the given ip into long ip. for example 255.255.50.51 into long ip.

Then you can compare whether the long ip for this given ip is between the converted long ips in the blacklist. If it is then it is not allowed else it is.

```
$ips = array("ip1", "ip2");
foreach($ips as $ip){
 $ip1 = str_replace("*", "0", $ip);
 $ip2 = str_replace("*", "255", $ip);

 $ip1 = ip2long($ip1);
 $ip2 = ip2long($ip2);
 $givenip = $_GET["ip"];
 $givenip = ip2long($givenip);

 if($givenip >= $ip1 && $ip <= $givenip){
   echo "blacklist ip hit between {$ip1} and {$ip2} on {$ip}";
 }
}
```

Comment: +1 for ip2long and numeric comparison instead of string comparison

Comment: second IP in list would break your solution: `192.168.2.1*` will become `192.168.2.10` and `192.168.2.1255`. While the first one is not exactly what we wanted, the second is a completely illegal IP address :)

Comment: Shouldn't `$ip <= $givenip` become `$givenip <= $ip2` in order to detect the range x.x.x.0 - x.x.x.255 ?

Comment: Agreed with @Lekensteyn -- it's clear that the range is determined using `$ip1` and `$ip2` (I would change the names of these variables to `$ipStart` and `$ipEnd` to make this clearer, by the way).

Comment: ip2 is never used. it should be $givenip >= $ip1 && $givenip <= $ip2

Answer (score 5):

Remove the asterisks and just do:

```
$ips = array('192.168.1.', '10.0.0.');

foreach ($ips as $ip) {
    if (strpos($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $ip) === 0) {
        // match
    }
}
```

Comment: just wrote what i wanted to write (nice solution!).

Comment: what about `192.168.*.*`? You'd also need to remove `..` from the $ip string.

Comment: Would not catch something like that: 255.*.255.255.

Answer (score 2):

This one allows all cases in the question plus short masks with no asterisks like 123.123.

```
/**
 * Checks given IP against array of masks like 123.123.123.123, 123.123.*.101, 123.123., 123.123.1*.*
 *
 * @param $ip
 * @param $masks
 * @return bool
 */
public static function checkIp($ip, $masks)
{
    if (in_array($ip, $masks)) {
        return true;  // Simple match
    } else {
        foreach ($masks as $mask) {
            if (substr($mask, -1) == '.' AND substr($ip, 0, strlen($mask)) == $mask) {
                return true; // Case for 123.123. mask
            }
            if (strpos($mask, '*') === false) {
                continue; // No simple matching and no wildcard in the mask, leaves no chance to match
            }
            // Breaking into triads
            $maskParts = explode('.', $mask);
            $ipParts = explode('.', $ip);
            foreach ($maskParts as $key => $maskPart) {
                if ($maskPart == '*') {
                    continue;  // This triad is matching, continue with next triad
                } elseif (strpos($maskPart, '*') !== false) {
                    // Case like 1*, 1*2, *1
                    // Let's use regexp for this
                    $regExp = str_replace('*', '\d{0,3}', $maskPart);
                    if (preg_match('/^' . $regExp . '$/', $ipParts[$key])) {
                        continue;  // Matching, go to check next triad
                    } else {
                        continue 2;  // Not matching, Go to check next mask
                    }
                } else {
                    if ($maskPart != $ipParts[$key]) {
                        continue 2; // If triad has no wildcard and not matching, check next mask
                    }
                    // otherwise just continue
                }
            }
            // We checked all triads and all matched, hence this mask is matching
            return true;
        }
        // We went through all masks and none has matched.
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a regular expression?

```
 preg_match("((192\\.168\\.1)|(10\\.0\\.0)|(127\\.0\\.0)\\.[012]\\d{0,2}|(\\:\\:1))",$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
```

Comment: I suppose I could dynamically generate a regex to based on the contents of the array. I updated the question to make it more obvious that the filter array will be dynamic.

Comment: this solution is not necessary "optimized" as the question requires. Generally, IPs are better treated as integers (unsigned or long) and comparing an integer against an array of integers is faster that matching an array of regular expressions against a string (i.e. ip)

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, I'm going to over-engineer this. Well, unless you have a fairly long list to match against.

Assuming you're only using wildcards to mean "I don't care about this octet", then you can parse each entry in your array into four values (one per octet). Say that you use -1 to mean wildcard, 0–255 means to match that value exactly. (If you need better performance than O(n), where *n* is the size of the match list, then there are better data structures you can use here—a trie, for example.) Call this array L. Of course, you only need do this once—not per-request.

You can then parse the remote address the same way (except without wildcards). You can also catch REMOTE_ADDR not being in the expected format here It now becomes fairly trivial to check matches:

```
has_match(ip) =
  for n in [0 … L.length)
    if (-1 == L.n.0 || L.n.0 = ip.0) && (-1 == L.n.1 || L.n.1 == ip.1) && …
      return true
  return false
```

(That's pseudo-code, of course)

Comment: @stereofrog: I'm afraid I've never used Refal (nor heard of it before you mentioned it). Its quite possible I've read pseudo-code from someone who has, though. I'm not quite sure how it resembles my pseudo-code, though... other than `.` for subscripts.

Answer (score 0):

This one is based on preg_match(), you provide the pattern and the subject to test it against.

```
/**
 * ip_match("172.30.20.*", "172.30.20.162"); // true
 * ip_match("172.30.20", "172.30.20.162"); // true; works if incomplete
 * ip_match("172.30.*.12", "172.30.20.12"); // true
 * ip_match("172.30.*.12", "172.30.20.11"); // false
 * ip_match("172.30.20.*", "172.30.20.*"); // true; wildcards in the subject will match with wildcards in the pattern
 * ip_match("172.30.20.12", "172.30.*.*"); // false
 * 
 * @param $pattern  The pattern to test against as a string
 * @param $subject  The input string
 *
 *  @return bool
 *
 */
function ip_match($pattern, $subject) {
    $pattern = explode(".", trim($pattern, "."));
    $pattern = array_pad($pattern, 4, "*");
        
    $subject = explode(".", trim($subject, "."));
    $subject = array_pad($subject, 4, "1");
        
    foreach ($pattern as $i => $octet) {
        if ($octet != "*" && $subject[$i] != $octet) {
            return false;
        }
    }
        
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function ipArrCheck($allowedIPArr = [], $IP = '')
{
    $IP_ARR    = explode('.', $IP);
    $resultArr = [];
    foreach ($IP_ARR as $IPkey => $IPvalue) {
        foreach ($allowedIPArr as $IPArrKey => $IPArrValue) {
            $checkIPArr = explode('.', $IPArrValue);
            $resultArr[$IPArrKey][$IPkey] = $checkIPArr[$IPkey] == $IP_ARR[$IPkey] || $checkIPArr[$IPkey] == '*';
        }
    }

    foreach ($resultArr as $value) {
        if (count(array_unique($value)) == 1 && current($value)) {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}

$MY_IP          = '192.168.52.10';
$ALLOWED_IP_ARR = ['127.0.0.1', '192.168.*.*'];

var_dump(ipArrCheck($ALLOWED_IP_ARR, $MY_IP));
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.