# Comparing IP addresses in PHP

Tags: php, network-programming, ip

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php

    class visitors
    {
        static $i;
        function __construct()
        {
            $this->checkIp();
        }
        function createFile()
        {
            $fp=fopen("visit.txt","a+");
            if($fp)
            {
            echo "<br /> File created";
            return $fp;
            }
            else
            {
                echo "File creation Error Check permissions";
                exit;
            }
        }
        function fetchIp()
        {
            $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            //$ip=ip2long($ip);
            return $ip;
        }
        function writeFile()
        {
            $fp=$this->createFile();
            $ip=$this->fetchIp();
            //echo $ip;
            $space="\r\n";
            fwrite($fp,$ip.$space);
            //self::$i++;
            //echo self::$i;

        }
        function checkIp()
        {
            $fp=$this->createFile();
            $ip=$this->fetchIp();
            while(!feof($fp))
            {
                $data.=fgets($fp);
            }
            $uip=explode("\r\n",$data);
            foreach($uip as $key)
            {
                if(strpos($key,$ip)!==0)
                {
                    $this->writeFile();
                }

            }
        }

    }
    $v=new visitors();
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I am trying to store the each visitors ip address in a text file and if the same visitor comes for the second time his ip will be written in the text file.To implement this I read the file and compare with the current ip and if they are same it doesn't call the write function.The problem is everything works but the file gets written everytime with the same ip in the newline.The comparison part fails.Please help me fix this.Leave the static i variable part.I have commented that so no problem with that.Thank you.

Note:
I have read [An optimized method to compare IP addresses with wildcards in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613002/an-optimized-method-to-compare-ip-addresses-with-wildcards-in-php) and got the strpos idea from that.Before that I used ip2long and long2ip but it too resulted in the same error.I also read PHP doesn't support unsigned integers from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php).Will this affect my compare operation as ip address is an unsigned 32 bit integer.

Comment: Finding a value in a plaintext file quickly gets very slow the larger the file grows. A database is a better solution!

Comment: Yeah I know that.Anyway thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to loop every time, just use [stristr()](http://uk.php.net/stristr) to see if the IP is there.

Change function

```
    function checkIp()
    {
        $fp=$this->createFile();
        $ip=$this->fetchIp();
        while(!feof($fp))
        {
            $data.=fgets($fp);
        }
        $uip=explode("\r\n",$data);
        foreach($uip as $key)
        {
            if(strpos($key,$ip)!==0)
            {
                $this->writeFile();
            }

        }
    }
```

with

```
    function checkIp()
    {
        $fp=$this->createFile();
        $ip=$this->fetchIp();
        while(!feof($fp))
        {
            $data.=fgets($fp);
        }
        if(!stristr($data, $ip)){
            $this->writeFile();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Because you are checking every line for match, if one of the lines does not match it will write your IP. Even if you access from same IP, last line is blank .. so again, it will write.

Answer (score 1):

A common way to remember ip's is to store them in a database. that way, you always have a record of their ip's and even more if you would like. =)

Best of luck

Comment: if you would like, i can help you write them. I do it all day long anyways. just tell me what are the column names, the table name and what has to equal what and ill write it

Comment: Thank you mic I don't need it now.

Comment: Your welcome. if i have helped at all please vote up my answer

Comment: I don't mind voting you up but believe me it's waste.I have did this in my previous questions and somebody votes them down in a day or two.Anyways try your luck I will do.Come to chat if possible.